# Function to get Row and column of panda dataset

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv dataset with texts. I need to search through them. I couldn't find an easy way to search for a string in a dataset and get the row and column indexes. For example, let's say the dataset is like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"China": ['Xi','Lee','Hung'], "India": ['Roy','Rani','Jay'], "England": ['Tom','Sam','Jack']})
```

Now let's say I want to find the string 'rani' and know its location. Is there a simple function to do that? Or do I have to loop through everything to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how this will scale but it works

`df[df.eq('Rani')].dropna(1, how='all').dropna()`

```
  India
1  Rani
```

Answer (score 1):

One vectorized (and therefore relatively scalable) solution to this is to leverage `numpy.where`:

```py
import numpy as np

np.where(df == 'Rani')
```

This returns two arrays, corresponding to column and row indices:

```
(array([1]), array([1]))
```

---

You can continue to take advantage of vectorized operations, but also write a more complicated filtering function, like so:

```py
np.where(df.applymap(lambda x: "ani" in x))
```

In other words, "apply to each cell the function that returns True if 'ani' is in the cell", and then conduct the same np.where filtering step.

You can use any function:

```py
def _should_include_cell(cell_contents):
    return cell_contents.lower() == "rani" or "Xi" in cell_contents

np.where(df.applymap(_should_include_cell)
```

---

Some final notes:

- `applymap` is slower than simple equality checking
- if you need this to scale WAY up, consider using [dask](https://docs.dask.org) instead of pandas

Comment: This is amazingly fast. Can this find a string instead of the full name. For example 'ani' instead of Rani?